# How can I add additional metadata into the django.server logs?

Tags: python, django, logging

What I am trying to do is as given below,

- The current logs for the server requests look like the following.

```
[29/Nov/2023 02:33:50] "GET /api/health/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31
```

- The new format I need is as following.

```
[29/Nov/2023 02:33:50] "GET /api/health/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31 user-id:<user_id>
```

I tried to add a logs filter.

```
"django.server": {
             "()": "django.utils.log.ServerFormatter",
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s user_id:%(user_id)s  ",
        }
```

The following is my filter.

```
class UserIdFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        user_id = None
        if hasattr(record, "request"):
            try:
                user_id = record.request.user.id
            except Exception as exp:
                user_id = "anon"
        if not user_id:
           user_id = "unknown"
        record.user_id = user_id
        return True
```

The problem is the `record` object above is a `socket.socket` object and does not have any request http payload metadata.

What could I do differently to find and append the request user_id to the logs?

Comment: If you've received a `socket.socket` object in your filter method, you've perhaps wired things up very strangely. Hard to tell from just the code you've posted.

Comment: I think you are confusing something here. You posted the log of your webserver (most likely nginx or apache). This can be configured by the config of the server you are using. The logs of Django (most likely run by gunicorn or uwsgi) are separate from the logs of your server.